# Fast booting Chromium-only Linux

Tags: chrome, distribution-choice

I have a controller that offers GUI/Cockpit View over HTTP as a single-page application (SPA).

My project is now to have a Cockpit computer that displays this "website" (SPA) and nothing more.

**I need a Linux which boots super fast, the ideal would be 10-15 seconds, into Chromium.**

... because nobody wants to wait half a minute to see engine data (like the HUD display in modern cars).

There need to be nothing more on this Linux system except

- Xorg with Intel drivers
- Chromium

Runs on Intel Atom x5-Z8350 x64. EFI takes 1 second.

---

I already tried a bare Debian, but I could only strip it down to 24 seconds (power-on to page loaded)

Can someone point me in the right direction? Is there maybe a distribution that fits my use case exactly? I don't know the search terms for such a thing.

`Systemd-analyze plot`:
[image: output of 'systemd-analyze plot']

I've made a video of the boot process. The system is booted as soon as the test site shows yellow "three.js" text.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2_XqE-hTYcg

Comment: Could you share a breakdown of your boot process with us? `apt install pastebinit; systemd-analyze plot | pastebinit` and share the link to the resultant SVG with us :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Here is the log/svg: https://drop.x64.eu/$/7rvjR

Comment: That, sadly, already looks pretty clean :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller do you see any potential in trying a bare Arch or even use buildroot to avoid the big systemd?

Comment: hey, this, by the way, says, you're at graphical.target after 14s. Is it possible your chromium takes 10s to load?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easy to tell at what point it is jammed when it's as slow as this?

Comment: @TomYan I've attached a youtube video. A big portion of the time is for init ramdisk and some MMC cleaning which I don't understand.

Comment: Hmm, the kernel and initrd loading does look quite slow. I wonder if it has something to do the the version of grub you are using. Also maybe they are large and your storage is slow. Not familiar with Debian but avoid initrd / initramfs that contains unnecessary drivers might help as well. As for the "cleaning" (it's actually filesystem check that tells you the fs is clean), I don't think it's stalling but it's just the systemd output is hidden. To be fair, that part does not seem particularly slow anyway when comparing with the X/browser part.

Comment: ah GRUB takes 3.2s ? Maybe it's actually waiting for 3 seconds for input?

Answer (score 1):

Optimizing boot processes on systemd systems usually works well based on looking at the SVGs produced by `systemd-analyze`; you don't even need root privileges, IIRC:

```
systemd-analyze plot > boot.svg
firefox boot.svg
```

Now, if you figure you've really disabled  or even masked all the systemd units that you don't need, and there's no things to be done like lazy-mounting network file systems or hard-coding IPv4 addresses instead of waiting for DHCP, another thing that tends to take time is storage bringup. Ext4 tends to take a bit longer to check its journal on boot than does XFS, for example, in my experience, but I don't think that'll be noticable on an eMMC. What might make more of a difference is using a compressed root file system: loading a whole operating system and even much worse chromium from eMMC uncompressed probably takes longer than decompressing it; I'd bet the bottleneck is storage bandwidth, not CPU power. Btrfs and ZFS support compression; I think for an eMMC device, having / (or /usr and maybe /var) reside on a F2FS with zstd compression (needs Linux >= 5.7; else use default LZO) would be a smart choice; it was heavily optimized for exactly that use case.

For example, I use LVM on all of my systems (out of principle. I just don't want to ever deal with "oh, if I could just extend this file system across disks" again or "there's no safe way to do an online backup", and I don't trust btrfs out of bad experience, sadly); that has to scan all storage devices for physical volumes. You can restrict that scanning using `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf`'s `filter` and `global_filter` directives in the `devices` section; see the explanatory text in your `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf`.

If all this doesn't help and your debian just depends on services that make your system wait, being in the critical path, as shown by `systemd-analyze critical-chain`, then, well, maybe debian is really too much for you! (Chances are: you can shave off a few more percents, but a system with the same capabilities will not magically boot three times as fast after all avoidable blockers).

But if you want to try: the pretty much standard way in automotive infotainment systems is doing an openembedded distro of your own! OpenEmbedded comes with a default x86 example that doesn't do much different to what you do. I bet someone somewhere has done some kind of documentation of how to build a kiosk system ;)

(I'm not experienced with buildroot at all aside from its roots, and these still make me not like it very much ;))

Comment: Thank you for all your input. I really appreciate it an will dig through all of that before marking this as answered.